# Transferir Variável por Href

Tags: php

Estou fazendo um sistema de consulta queria transferir uma variável por href, eu faço uma consulta por "status" ABERTO ou FECHADO após isso informo somente o ID para não ficar muita informação na tela, e precisava criar um href para outra pagina view expandindo o cadastro. Segue meu cod para entender melhor, se alguém tiver uma dica agradeço.

Controller:

```
    $palavra = $this->input->post("palavra");
    $usercadastro = $this->model_c->consultar($palavra);


    if ($usercadastro->num_rows() == 1) {
        $dados['consulta'] = $this->model_c->consultarnc();
        $this->load->view('ConsultaCadastro_v', $dados);

    }elseif ($usercadastro->num_rows() == 0) {
        $dados['consulta'] = $this->model_c->consultarnc02();
        $this->load->view('ConsultaCadastro_v', $dados);
    }

}
```

View:

```
<h1>RNCS</h1>
<hr />
<?php foreach ($consulta as $cadastro) : ?>
<p><strong>Bairro:</strong> <a  class="font-weight-bold" ><?php echo $cadastro->bairro ?></p></a>
<p><strong>Nome:</strong> <a  class="font-weight-bold" ><?php echo $cadastro->nome ?></p></a>
<p><strong>complemento:</strong> <a  class="font-weight-bold" ><?php echo $cadastro->complemento ?></p></a>
<hr />
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você precisa enviar pelo HREF o id? se for isso na hora de montar a pagina coloca no fim do HREF

```
?NOMEDAVAR=ID
```

Assim você vai ter acesso pela variável GET do php, usando $GET['NOMEDAVAR'] ai você pode montar a outra pagina com base nesse nessa var que vai ser o ID.

```
<a  class="font-weight-bold" href = "pagina.php?NOMEDAVAR=ID">
```

Comment: Obrigado Lucas!